# Pointing Numba to the TBB

Tags: python, numba, tbb

Is there a way to point numba to the latest version of the TBB installed on my virtual environment, please? By default, numba finds an outdated version of the TBB and resorts to OMP.

Here is the numba warning:

```
NumbaWarning: The TBB threading layer requires TBB version 2021 update 1 or later i.e., TBB_INTERFACE_VERSION >= 12010. Found TBB_INTERFACE_VERSION = 10003. The TBB threading layer is disabled.
```

Although the installed version of TBB is:

```
Name: tbb
Version: 2021.5.0
Summary: Intel® oneAPI Threading Building Blocks
Home-page: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onetbb.html
Author: Intel Corporation
Author-email: scripting@intel.com
License: Intel Simplified Software License
Location: c:\users\lucas\desktop\buy_bot\buybot\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tbb-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting the "TBBROOT" environment variable to the path where the latest TBB is installed.
Numba 0.54 will support TBB 2021, please check your Numba version.